# Drag and drop functionality for multiple divs (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a small thing where I want the user to be able to create any number of small window objects and then move them around independently on the screen like you would with normal windows. Later I will try to make it so that you can only grab the uppermost part of the windows.

The window objects will all be of the same type, `WindowObject`, or at least that's been the idea up until now.

The first thing I tried was putting the functionality inside of the objects themselves.

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
   <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red">example</div>
   <div style="width:100px; height:100px;background-color:red">example</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var WindowObject = function() {
    this.xPos = 0;
    this.yPos = 0;
};

WindowObject.prototype.addListeners = function() {
    this.test1 = this.mouseDown.bind(this);
    this.test2 = this.mouseUp.bind(this);
    this.container = document.querySelector("#container");

    this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", this.test1, false);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.test2, false);
};

WindowObject.prototype.move = function(event) {
    event.target.style.position = "absolute";
    event.target.style.top = (event.clientY - this.yPos) + "px";
    event.target.style.left = (event.clientX - this.xPos) + "px";
};

WindowObject.prototype.mouseUp = function() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.test3, true);
};

WindowObject.prototype.mouseDown = function(event) {
    this.xPos = event.clientX - event.target.offsetLeft;
    this.yPos = event.clientY - event.target.offsetTop;

    this.test3 = this.move.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.test3, true);
};
```

This kind of works if you drag the divs very slowly (so that the mouse never leaves them) and also make sure not to overlap other elements. Otherwise the position of the div gets messed up and if there are more than one you may find yourself dragging several divs at the same time.

I also tried putting the functionality in a different kind of object, with some smaller adjustments, but the result was the same.

If you think I should try a different approach all together, please let me know. If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.move.bind` .. i don't see a bind method on the move object.. also, why are you reinventing the wheel. there are dozens of libraries that already implement draggable popups. jquery being the moost obvious.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is a good way to learn, in my opinion, if that is the goal, of course.

Comment: Pamblam: I'm trying to learn, yes =) I'm kind of new to bind. How do you mean there is no bind method on the move object? The eventlistener on mousemove is added in the mousedown method.